# Trying to use multiple vertices with math mode names

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, graphs

I am working on a simple graph, using Ti*k*Z.

The code I have so far is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\graph[clockwise, n=3, V={i,j,k}, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}] { subgraph C_n };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The *output* I receive while compiling the code above is:

[image]

The only change I want to make is to display `$\mathbf{i}$` instead of i, `$\mathbf{j}$` instead of j and `$\mathbf{k}$` instead of k. When I try to do so, compiling doesn't work and I receive the following error message:

```
Undefined control sequence.
```

Comment: Please show what `When I try to do so` means.

Comment: Is `\graph[clockwise, n=3, V={i,j,k}, typeset=$\mathbf{\tikzgraphnodename}$, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}] { subgraph C_n };` what you want? With `V` you specify the name of the nodes. These can't have names that include `\mathbf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of names you specify for the [key `V`](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/V) is used for the *names* of the nodes. These kind of names don't allow “special” macros like `\mathbf`. (Node names are used as macro names internally by PGF and these need to be fully expandable to text. `\mathbf` is not and all hell breaks loose because of that.)

However, the `graphs` library provides the [`typeset` key](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#tikz/graphs/typeset) where you have access to certain macros, mainly the `\tikzgraphnodename` and the `\tikzgraphnodetext` macros (which are the same in this simple case):

```
\graph[
  clockwise,
  n=3,
  V={i,j,k},
  edge={bend left=45, -stealth},
  typeset=$\mathbf{\tikzgraphnodetext}$ % !or $\mathbf{\tikzgraphnodename}$
] { subgraph C_n };
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph[clockwise, n=3, V={i,j,k}, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}, % no typeset
  ] { subgraph C_n };
\tikz\graph[clockwise, n=3, V={i,j,k}, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}, % typeset with text
  typeset=$\mathbf{\tikzgraphnodetext}$] { subgraph C_n };
\tikz\graph[clockwise, n=3, V={i,j,k}, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}, % typeset with name
  typeset=$\mathbf{\tikzgraphnodename}$] { subgraph C_n };
\tikz\graph[clockwise, n=3, edge={bend left=45, -stealth}, % for fun
  typeset=$v_{\tikzgraphnodetext}$,
  nodes={text=red!\the\numexpr\tikzgraphnodetext00/3\relax!blue}
] { subgraph C_n };
\end{document}
```

---

Thanks to the [comment of Henri Menke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659116/trying-to-use-multiple-vertices-with-math-mode-names/659120?noredirect=1#comment1640196_659120), a small fix to the `subgraph I_n` (which is used internally by `subgraph C_n`) enables you to use the [full power of the `\graph` way of specifying a vertex](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs#sec-19.3.4).

However, as it uses a `\foreach` loop you need to protect `,` when they're used the node text or in the options (or in the node name but that's not a good idea to begin with).

```
V={ i / $\mathbf{i}$, j / $\mathbf{j}$, k / $\mathbf{k}$ [{red, fill=green}]}
```

or

```
V={ i / $\mathbf{i}$, j / $\mathbf{j}$, {k / $\mathbf{k}$ [red, fill=green]}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\makeatletter
\tikzgraphsset{
  declare={subgraph I_n}{
    \foreach \tikz@lib@graph@node@num in \tikzgraphV
      {[parse/.expand once=\tikz@lib@graph@node@num]}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tikz\graph[clockwise, n=3,
  V={ i / $\mathbf{i}$, j / $\mathbf{j}$, k / $\mathbf{k}$ },
  edge={bend left=45, -stealth}] { subgraph C_n };
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be possible to do `V={ i / $\mathbf{i}$, j / $\mathbf{j}$, k / $\mathbf{k}$ }`, but that is currently prevented by a bug. The loop variable `\tikz@lib@graph@node@num` is not expanded in the [definition of `subgraph I_n`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/89a9ef189a7420e0510fe97907285804bee4f670/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/graphs/tikzlibrarygraphs.standard.code.tex#L26-L27) which results in all of `i / $\mathbf{i}$` being parsed as the node name.

Comment: @HenriMenke I've tried that as an alternative but when it failed I went with the best next thing I know worked. The manual actually states that `V`s value is used for the vertex names which I understood to be plain node names but even better … I've added a "fix" for that bug in my updated answer.