# Deleting a node from a subgraph while mantaining the position of the other nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, tikz-graphs

Suppose I have a tikz graph like this one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}

\tikzset{v-label/.style={
every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=1},}} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[v-label,]
\graph[clockwise,radius=1cm,]{
subgraph I_n [n=5,V={f,g,h,i,j},]--subgraph C_n [n=5,V={a,b,c,d,e}];
f--h--j--g--i--f;
{[edges={very thick,red,}]e--j--g--b--c--h--f--i--d--e};};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And I wish to delete a vertex, say a, and all incident edges while mantaining the rest of the graph as it is. Like so:

[image]

What's the best way to do this? I've thought about manually positioning the vertices b,...,e but there's gotta be a better way, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A coordinate

With this [small fix to `subgraph I_n`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659120/16595) from a recent answer of mine you could define

```
\tikzgraphsset{
  hide me/.style={
    shape=coordinate,
    target edge style=move to,
    source edge style=move to}}
```

and use it as such:

```
   subgraph I_n [n=5,V={f,g,h,i,j}]
-- subgraph C_n [n=5,V={a[hide me],b,c,d,e}];
```

(We could also use `draw=none` instead of `move to`.)

Unfortunately, the bounding box will include this coordinate and the option `overlay` won't work.

#### An invisible node

It does interestingly work with a real node, i.e.

```
\tikzgraphsset{
  hide me/.style={
    draw=none, fill=none, overlay,
    /utils/exec=\def\tikzgraphnodetext{},
    target edge style=move to,
    source edge style=move to}
```

Since we don't want the node's name to show up we either have to use `a/[hide me]` (so that the node's text is the part between `/` and `[`, i.e. nothing) or as I did here, we set it to `{}`.

The mentioned fix is needed for the syntax `a[hide me]` not for the `hide me` style.

#### Only four nodes

Thirdly, you could just place only four nodes:

```
 subgraph I_n [n=5,V={f,g,h,i,j}];
{[circular placement, /tikz/shift=(-90:1cm), radius=2cm,
  chain polar shift=(-72:0cm), phase=18] b -- c -- d -- e};
```

The `chain polar shift` value makes sure the node are placed at the same radius with a distance of 72° (clockwise). The `phase` value makes sure that the `b` node is placed in the same position as before. (Initially, that value is `90` which leads to the first node always placed at the top.)

Why the `/tikz/shift` is necessary I can't tell you exactly. It looks like it  uses the `f` node (the first one of the previous subgraph) as the new center.
And this node is placed `at (90:1cm)` as per the default placement.

#### Only four nodes using `subgraph I_n`

We can use a bit of the magic of the built-in subgraphs by using

```
subgraph I_n [n=5, V={f,g,h,i,j}];
subgraph I_n [n=4, V={b,c,d,e}, radius=2cm, 
              group polar shift=(-72:0cm), phase=18];
d -- c;
```

where we have to specify the connections manually (`subgraph C_n` would connecnt `b` and `e`) but in your case only `d -- c` since all others you'd overdraw anyway in thick red.

Though, we still need to specify the radius and we can't connect the subgraphs by `--` because it would do `f -- b`, `g -- c` and so one.
We could probably phase the first subgraph and reorder the names and …

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs.standard}
\makeatletter
\tikzgraphsset{
  declare={subgraph I_n}{
    \foreach \tikz@lib@graph@node@num in \tikzgraphV
      {[parse/.expand once=\tikz@lib@graph@node@num]}}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  v-label/.style={
    every node/.style={circle,draw,minimum size=1.5em,inner sep=1}}}
\tikzgraphsset{% shortcut
  connect without a/.style={
    parse={f--h--j--g--i--f;
          {[edges={very thick,red}] e--j--g--b--c--h--f--i--d--e};}}}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  v-label,
  graphs/hide me/.style={
    shape=coordinate,
    target edge style=move to,
    source edge style=move to}
]
\graph[clockwise, radius=1cm]{
  subgraph I_n [n=5, V={f,g,h,i,j}]
--subgraph C_n [n=5, V={a[hide me],b,c,d,e}];
  {[connect without a]};
};

\tikz[
  v-label,
  graphs/hide me/.style={
    draw=none, fill=none, overlay,
    /utils/exec=\def\tikzgraphnodetext{},
    target edge style=move to,
    source edge style=move to}
]
\graph[clockwise, radius=1cm]{
  subgraph I_n [n=5, V={f,g,h,i,j}]
--subgraph C_n [n=5, V={a[hide me],b,c,d,e}];
  {[connect without a]};
};

\tikz[v-label]
\graph[clockwise, radius=1cm]{
   subgraph I_n [n=5, V={f,g,h,i,j}];
  {[circular placement, /tikz/shift=(-90:1cm), radius=2cm,
   chain polar shift=(-72:0cm), phase=18] b -- c -- d -- e};
  {[connect without a]};
};

\tikz[v-label]
\graph[clockwise, radius=1cm]{
  subgraph I_n [n=5, V={f,g,h,i,j}];
  subgraph I_n [n=4, V={b,c,d,e}, radius=2cm, 
                group polar shift=(-72:0cm), phase=18];
  d -- c;
  {[connect without a]};
};
\end{document}
```

### Output

The output is always the same, except the first one has a higher bounding box.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I went with the first option as it mantains a constant height between graphs, so if I remove a and f on two copies of the graph and place them side by side, it looks nicer.