# How do I enclose and color vertices?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

Does anyone know how to enclose and color the vertices?

```
% https://q.uiver.app/#q=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
\[\begin{tikzcd}[cramped,sep=tiny]
    &&&&&&& {v_2} \\
    \\
    \\
    {v_1} &&&&&&& {v_7} &&&&&&& {v_3} \\
    &&& {v_6} &&&&&&&& {v_8} \\
    \\
    \\
    \\
    &&&&& {v_{10}} &&&& {v_9} \\
    \\
    \\
    &&&& {v_5} &&&&&& {v_4}
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-8, to=4-1]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-8, to=4-8]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=4-1, to=5-4]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=9-6, to=12-5]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=4-1, to=12-5]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=9-10, to=12-11]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=12-5, to=12-11]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=9-6, to=4-8]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=4-8, to=9-10]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=5-4, to=5-12]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=9-6, to=5-12]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=9-10, to=5-4]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-8, to=4-15]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=4-15, to=5-12]
    \arrow[color={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=4-15, to=12-11]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Comment: Welcome. Quiver produces … questionable code. What do you mean by enclose and color? You can add `cells={nodes={draw=green}}` to have all vertices have their border drawn in green. If you want to color them indidividually add `|[draw=blue]|` at the start of the cells. Or maybe the [text should be colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692100)? Then use `text=red` instead of `draw`.

Comment: thanks, do i have to place [draw=blue] on the vertices?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 2):

The quiver software/website isn't really the best to get started with TikZ-CD, it's rather verbose. The [library's manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-cd/0) is rather short and has examples.

Here's the same diagram with `\ar`rows from inside the cells with the target specification and no unnecessary empty rows and columns.

It doesn't look good. TikZ-CD is not the best tool for this diagram.

---

I believe placing the nodes in a circular fashion is much better which is what I show in the other two diagrams via the [`graphs` libraries](https://tikz.dev/tikz-graphs).

The first diagram only uses subgraphs of the `graphs.standard` library, however it isn't easy to specify colors for individual nodes here (it will need [a small bugfix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/659120)) but you can do the same manual and just add things like `[blue]` or `[draw=red]` as usual.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, graphs.standard}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{214,92,92}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=.25em, row sep=1em, arrows={dash, Red}]
 & & & &          v_2 \ar[d] \ar[dllll] \ar[drrrr] \\
                  v_1 \ar[dr] \ar[dddrr]
 & & & &          v_7 \ar[ddl]\ar[ddr]
         & & & &  v_3 \ar[dl] \ar[dddll] \\
 &       |[blue]| v_6 \ar[rrrrrr] \ar[rrrrd]
   & & & & & &    v_8 \ar[dllll] \\
 & & &            v_{10}
       & &        v_9 \\
 & & |[draw=red]| v_5 \ar[ru]\ar[rrrr]
     & & & &      v_4 \ar[lu]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\tikz\graph[
  edges=Red, simple, radius=1.5cm,
  clockwise=5, phase=90+360/5,
  typeset=$v_{\tikzgraphnodename}$]{
  subgraph K_n[V={6, ..., 10}] --
  subgraph C_n[n=5]; % n = 5 is the same as V = {1, ..., 5}
  subgraph C_n[V={6, ..., 10}, -!-]% remove the cycle, needs simple
};
\]
\[
\tikz\graph[
  edges=Red, simple, radius=1.5cm,
  clockwise=5, phase=90+360/5,
  typeset=$v_{\tikzgraphnodename}$]{
  {[clique] 6[blue], 7, 8, 9, 10} --
  {[cycle] 1, 2, 3, 4, 5[draw=red]},
  subgraph C_n[V={6, ..., 10}, -!-]% remove the cycle, needs simple
};
\]
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you.
Is it possible to completely paint the rectangle where $v_5$ is located?

Comment: @Tomais Yes, just use `fill = green`. You can do the same actions on a node's path as you can [with a normal path](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions).