# coloring and labeling in quiver tikz

Tags: tikz-cd

@Qrrbrbirlbel, thank you very much for the response to this link:[How do I enclose and color vertices?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/693666/how-do-i-enclose-and-color-vertices), how do I make the yellow circle see its label?

I send you my latex code :

```
%https://q.uiver.app/#q=WzAsNixbNCwxXSxbMywxLCJ2XzQiXSxbMywzLCJ2XzUiXSxbMCw0LCJ2XzMiXSxbMCwyLCJ2XzIiXSxbMCwwLCJ2XzEiXSxbNSwxLCIiLDAseyJjb2xvdXIiOlswLDYwLDYwXSwic3R5bGUiOnsiaGVhZCI6eyJuYW1lIjoibm9uZSJ9fX1dLFszLDEsIiIsMix7ImNvbG91ciI6WzAsNjAsNjBdLCJzdHlsZSI6eyJoZWFkIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJub25lIn19fV0sWzQsMiwiIiwwLHsiY29sb3VyIjpbMCw2MCw2MF0sInN0eWxlIjp7ImhlYWQiOnsibmFtZSI6Im5vbmUifX19XSxbNSwyLCIiLDIseyJjb2xvdXIiOlswLDYwLDYwXSwic3R5bGUiOnsiaGVhZCI6eyJuYW1lIjoibm9uZSJ9fX1dXQ==
\[\begin{tikzcd}[cramped] 
    |[blue] [draw=blue, circle]| {v_1} \\
    &&&  {v_4} & {} \\
|[blue]     [draw=blue, circle]| {v_2} \\
    &&& {v_5} \\
|[red] [fill, yellow] [draw=blue, circle]|  {v_3}
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=5-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=3-1, to=4-4]
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-1, to=4-4]
\end{tikzcd}\]
```

Comment: Please complete MWE!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please always provide a complete MWE starting with `\documentclass` end ending with `\end{document}` that shows the packages you use.

Comment: Here's a checklist you can use to turn your code fragment into a MWE, you can post instead: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code line

```
|[red] [fill, yellow] [draw=blue, circle]|  {v_3}
```

is not correct. It should be

```
|[red] [circle, draw=blue, fill=yellow]|  {v_3} % <---
```

Complete MWE than is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, graphs.standard}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{214,92,92}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped]
    |[blue] [draw=blue, circle]| {v_1} \\
    &&&  {v_4} & {} \\
|[blue]     [draw=blue, circle]| {v_2} \\
    &&& {v_5} \\
|[red] [circle, draw=blue, fill=yellow]|  {v_3} % <---
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=5-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=3-1, to=4-4]
    \arrow[draw={rgb,255:red,214;green,92;blue,92}, no head, from=1-1, to=4-4]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
See, if the following, much shorter code for your diagram is acceptable for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, graphs.standard}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{214,92,92}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped,
               arrows= {Red, no head}
               ]
|[blue, draw=blue, circle]| {v_1} \\
    &&&  {v_4} & {} \\
|[blue, draw=blue, circle]| {v_2} \\
    &&& {v_5} \\
|[red, circle, draw=blue, fill=yellow]|  {v_3} % <---
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=4-4]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

or

```
%\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd, graphs.standard}
\definecolor{Red}{RGB}{214,92,92}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[cramped,
               arrows= {Red, no head},
               cells = {nodes={circle, draw=blue, text=blue}}
               ]
v_1 \\
    &&&     |[draw=none]|   v_4 \\
v_2 \\
    &&&     |[draw=none]|   v_5     \\
|[fill=yellow, text=red]|   v_3 
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=5-1, to=2-4]
    \arrow[from=3-1, to=4-4]
    \arrow[from=1-1, to=4-4]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

Results are the same as before.